# Iterating a model that contains values too low

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder

Beginner Python programmer here,

I have exported my Model Builder model from ArcGIS to Python. What I am trying to do is provide some kind of clause saying "if the data selected has less than 2 records/features, skip it and go to the next iteration."

I have found information on SearchCursors and CurrentStates, but I am look at the entire feature. Not just the one field.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description are you looking for [Get Count](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm)?

> Returns the total number of rows for a table.
>   If the input is a layer or table view containing a selected set of records, only the selected records will be counted.

Comment: Ah, yes. I couldn't find something like that in my search, so I thought there would be something simpler going the python route/trying to expand my python knowledge.. 

Thank you.

Comment: Also, as the last example in the documentation shows, Get Count doesn't return a count - it returns a Result object, which contains the resulting count as a string!

Comment: Is there anyway to modify the long integer at all? The description states if there are no records, but what if I want if there is 1 or less?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that with a precondition, but it's certainly something you can do with standard python looping. Get the count as shown in the example, and if it's under your threshold use a CONTINUE to skip it.